# spring cloud kafka binder exponential retry on Runtime exception and send to dlq on deserialization exception

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Here is the code i have, I could either send deserialization exception to dlq topic or retry the event exponentially, I want to have both, is it possible to have both using kafka binder. Thanks.

```
 @Bean
    public DlqPartitionFunction partitionFunction() {
        return (group, consumerRecord, ex) -> consumerRecord.partition();
    }

    @Bean
    public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer(DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        return (container, dest, group) -> container.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recovered) {
        // Do not try to recover from validation exceptions when validation of orders failed
        var errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(recovered, new FixedBackOff(0L, 1L));
        errorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(javax.validation.ValidationException.class);
        return errorHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer publisher(KafkaOperations kafkaOperations) {
        return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(
                kafkaOperations,
                (consumerRecord, exception) -> {
                    log.error("Sending corruption record to DLQ with key {}", consumerRecord.key(), exception);
                    MetricsLogger.incrementCount(dlqErrorCount);
                    return new TopicPartition(dlqTopicName, 0);
                }
        );


//This is for exponential retry.
    @Bean
    ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer() {
        ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries exponentialBackOff = new    ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries(100);
        exponentialBackOff.setInitialInterval(10_000L);
        exponentialBackOff.setMultiplier(2.0);
        exponentialBackOff.setMaxInterval(1_800_000L); 
        return (container, dest, group) -> {
            container.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(
                    exponentialBackOff));
        };
    }
    }
```

not able to have both exponential retry and sending to dlq on deserialization exception.